# Estimating an integral with a singularity at the interval's endpoint

Tags: na.numerical-analysis

I am trying to obtain an analytic estimate of this integral:

$\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\exp\left(-a(x-x_0)^2\right) dx$,

where $a\gg1$, $x_0\in[0,1]$. Saddle-point approximation doesn't work due to infinite derivative of $1/\sqrt{x}$ at 0. Any tips on how to get a handle on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: Might the substitution x=t^2 help?

Comment: That substitution doesn't help with respect to saddle-point approximation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, now you tell us that $x_0$ depends on $a$. If $x_0$ is of order $1/\sqrt{a}$, set $x_0=y_0/\sqrt{a}$, $x=y/\sqrt{a}$, and your integral becomes
$$a^{-1/4}\int_0^{\sqrt{a}}{1\over\sqrt{y}}\exp(-(y-y_0)^2)\,dy.$$
Up to exponentially small error, you can replace the upper bound of $\sqrt{a}$ by $\infty$.

Comment: No, $x_0$ doe not depend on $a$. I mean that I need the value of the integral for all $x_0\in [0,1]$, including the region $x_0\sim 1/\sqrt{a}$. Sorry if my comment was unclear.

Comment: If $x_0$ does not depend on $a$, then either $x_0 = 0$ (which does require a different analysis) or $x_0 > 0$, in which case $a x_0^2 \to \infty$ as $a \to \infty$.  If you want something for $x_0 \sim 1/\sqrt{a}$, that says $x_0$ _does_ depend on $a$.

Comment: For $x_0 = 0$, i.e. $y_0 = 0$, Maple says 
$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} {\rm exp}(-y^2)\, dy = \frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{2 \Gamma(3/4)}$ so your integral is asymptotic to 
$\frac{\pi \sqrt{2}}{2 \Gamma(3/4)} a^{-1/4}$.

Comment: If $x_0/\sqrt{a}$ is bounded, the calculation above works. If $x_0/\sqrt{a}$ is large, the saddle point method works.

Comment: I am interested in this integral as a function of $x_0$ for fixed large, but finite $a$. The interval of values $x_0\in[0, \sqrt{a}]$ is of particular interest.

Comment: Put another way, there's still problem of analytic estimate for

$\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}\exp(-(y-y_0)^2)dy$

and the saddle-point approximation doesn't work for $у_0\in[0,1]$. Sure, it's easy to get the value $2\ \Gamma\left(5/4\right)$ for this integral when $y_0=0$, but that wasn't my question.

Comment: Mathematica gives the value

$${\pi\over 2}\sqrt{y_0}e^{-y_0^2/2}(I_{-1/4}(y_0^2/2)+I_{1/4}(y_0^2/2)),$$

Comment: OK, I missed that this integral evaluates exactly. Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

Saddle-point approximation should work fine, if $x_0 > 0$.  If the singularity at 0 bothers you, integrate instead from $x_0/2$ to 1: the integral from $0$ to $x_0/2$ is $O(exp(-a x_0^2/4))$.

Comment: This doesn't produce the correct behaviour in the region $x_0\sim 1/\sqrt{a}$, which I do need.